# How to pass a parameter into Control.onAdd in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have the following code:

```
var legend = new L.Control({position: 'bottomright'});
             legend.onAdd = function (map,max,min) {
             var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
             var grades = [];
             console.log("Maximium ligne 139: "+ max);
             console.log("increament ligne 329" + min);
             var min;
             var ccount;
             var increament = (61544-4161)/8;
             for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
                 console.log("What we got! " +increament);
                 grades.push(Math.round(increament*i));
             }
            // grades = [0, 200, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3500, 5000],
            var labels = [];

                 // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
                 for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                     div.innerHTML +=
                     '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1, 61544,4161) + '"></i> ' +
                     grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
                 }

                 return div;
             };
```

I'm trying to customize my map legend in leaflet. Therefore I need to pass some parameters and treat them inside the function in ligne 2.

I've tried to read the variables using this.max // this.min but its not working. Also I tried to pass the parameters inside the function (see line 2) but with no success. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183872/leaflet-custom-info-control-update-with-extra-parameters). You can use the legend.update function for extra parameters, if you'll give the extra parameters a default value.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to encapsulate the leaflet control inside a function. Something like this:

```
const legend = (yourProp: string) => {
   const control = new L.Control({position: 'topright'});
   control.onAdd = function () {
      let div = L.DomUtil.create('div');
      div.innerHtml = `<span>${yourProp}</span>`
      return div;
   }
   return control;    
}
legend("My Title").addTo(map);
```